# Put '00's in front of integers based on how large the number is?

Tags: r, vector, printf

I have a vector of calendar days such as `vec_day`

```
vec_day<- c(8,14,365,9)
vec_day
[1]   8  14 365   9
```

I would like to transform this to `vec_day2`

```
vec_day2     
[1] "008" "014" "365" "009"
```

It can be either a string or a vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec_day2 <- sprintf("%03d", vec_day)
[1] "008" "014" "365" "009"
```

Comment: it would be good to take a look at the `sprintf` help page via `?sprintf` in the R console. tons of options that will be invaluable to your success in R.